# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "Carthage binary is not found."

Tags: xcode, appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

Every time i try to start appium desktop with the iOS capabilities i am getting the following error:

> Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "Carthage binary is not found. Install using `brew install carthage` if it is not installed and make sure the root folder, where carthage binary is installed, is present in PATH environment variable.

Complete appium log can be found on the following [link](https://gist.github.com/timetraveler90/435d09313e2ada1a3770f0803b2cf6ec)

Capabilities used for this are:

```
{
"platformName": "iOS",
"deviceName": "iPhone X",
"app": "path/to/my/App.app",
"platformVersion": "11.2",
"automationName": "XCUITest",
"xcodeOrgId": "myXcodeOrgId",
"bundleId": "bundleIdOfMyApp"
}
```

*which carthage* output is **/usr/local/bin/carthage** and the version of carthage is **0.28.0**

XCode version is **Version 9.2 (9C40b)**

Comment: Install cathrage

Answer (score 10):

You need to first install Carthage on your machine by executing below command on your terminal

```
$ brew install carthage
```

For more details refer [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest/#basic-setup).

Comment: I faced this issue even when the carthage was already installed, just do 'brew reinstall carthage' in such case. This salved problem for me.

Comment: Sadly, it did not work for me. Even after upgrading carthage's version, i am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Check if your base path is set properly in your bash profile.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.You can try to reinstall appium on macOS Desktop.
https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.6.3
select appium-desktop-1.6.3-mac.zip

Comment: Add some description jere

Comment: I don't know how did this happen，But I solved the problem with this steps.
First time I install appium but the sever don't set up. So appium on my macOS don't have the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Carthage Folder, Check in below path /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent

**Carthage Folder** If it is not there, Follow Below steps

**Step-1**: For Appium 1.15.1 and above

Open below path in Terminal
$ cd /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules

$ sudo chmod -R 777 . appium-webdriveragent/*

**Step-2:** goto 1) $ cd /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent

2) sudo mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle

3) sudo sh ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d

**Step-3:** Build WebDriverAgent Project with sign

Open below project in XCode /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj